# does Editing Metatada create a new copy of the file?

Tags: versioning

in a document library where the versioning is enabled, when I edit the properties of a file, I will have a version 2 but will I have a new copy of this file in the DB ?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you've versioning turned on then any checkout/checkin will create a copy of the file in the database. If the file is in a Office fileformat it'll also be updated with inside the file.